# Add new column with column names

Tags: r

I have this `df`:

```
        A       B   C 
1       NA    100   NA
2      130     NA   NA
3       NA     NA   200
4      110     NA   NA
```

I'm going to `bind` them, remove the `NA`'s so i get one single column with their values.

But i need to keep the information from where they came, so i'd like to add a new column with the `column_name`, so it would come out like this:

```
      values  column_name 
1       130    A 
2       110    A
3       100    B
4       200    C
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a job for `stack` from base R,

```
s_df <- stack(df)
s_df[complete.cases(s_df),]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    values ind
> 2     130   A
> 4     110   A
> 5     100   B
> 11    200   C
> ```

**EDIT** A one liner version of the above (as per @snoram's comment)

```
stack(df)[!is.na(df),]
```

Comment: one liner: `stack(df)[!is.na(df),]`

Comment: Another one-liner: `na.omit(stack(df))`

Answer (score 4):

Using tidyr and dplyr:

```
df1 %>% 
  gather(column, values) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(values))

  column values
1      A    130
2      A    110
3      B    100
4      C    200
```

Or as @Kath mentioned in the comments:

```
df1 %>% 
      gather(column, values, na.rm = T)
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(NA, 130L, NA, 110L), B = c(100L, NA, NA, 
NA), C = c(NA, NA, 200L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 4):

One option using base R is `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` where we get the indices of non-NA values and get it's corresponding column names.

```
indx <- which(!is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(values = df[indx], column = names(df)[indx[,2]])

#  values column
#1    130      A
#2    110      A
#3    100      B
#4    200      C
```

---

Or another option without `which`

```
indx <- !is.na(df)
data.frame(values = df[indx], column = rep(names(df), colSums(indx)))

#  values column
#1    130      A
#2    110      A
#3    100      B
#4    200      C
```

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` version using `melt` to put data in the long format and filtering missing values:

```
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(dx))[!is.na(value)]

  variable value
1:        A   130
2:        A   110
3:        B   100
4:        C   200
```

Where dx is :

```
dx = read.table(text="       A       B   C 
1       NA    100   NA
2      130     NA   NA
3       NA     NA   200
4      110     NA   NA",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

### update (elegant)

You can also use `na.rm` to filter missing values:

```
melt(setDT(dx),na.rm=TRUE)
```